Create and download the JSON file in iOS app by using ionic vue
Download the JSON data file into iOS mobile local default folder by using ionic Vue.
Download JSON file by using ionic Vue in iOS app.
Step by step code for to downloading JSON file into local folder by using ionic vue and swift code

https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask
